# How to declare a complex type array in fortran 90

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90, complex-numbers

I need some help to initialize a complex type 1-D array in Fortran on linux

```
complex(kind=dp),dimension(8),public:: zc = (/(0.0_dp,0.0_dp) ,(-3.496991526333D001,0.0_dp) ,
( -3.944481647220D+000 , 0.0_dp ) , (-4.294180799072D+000 , 0.0_dp ) , 
(-4.294180799072D+000, -1.0_dp) , ( -3.944481647220D+000,-1.0_dp ) , 
(-3.496991526333D-           001,-1.0_dp ) , (0.0_dp,-1.0_dp)/) ! z computational
```

Above statement works in Fortran Power Station( for Windows ) but not on Linux. It gives the following error

```
Missing ')' in statement at or before (1)
```

**NOTE :** The '1' is the comma b/w 3rd and 4th complex   no.
The extension of the program is .f90

Comment: In what compiler on Linux? Which source form is that? On which column starts it?

Comment: @VladimirF, Thank you very much . The code worked using the ampersands. From the extension, I could conclude that I was using free form(.f90) . But if I left a space between opening parenthesis and slash, it gave a compilation error. So spaces are also important. I placed an ampersand after each complex number and then continued on a fresh line. Thank you again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the correct way of continuing lines. If you use fixed form (usually `.f`,`.form`) place any character on the sixth column of the new line  and then your statement. You probably use this, otherwise `-3.496991526333D-           001` coudn't work, because spaces are important in the free form. But `!` denotes comments in the free form. If you use the free form, correct the number. Be sure to not go past column 72 in the fixed form.

For example:

```
      complex(kind=dp),dimension(8),public:: zc = (/(0.0_dp,0.0_dp) ,(-3.496991526333D001,0.0_dp) ,
     *  ( -3.944481647220D+000 , 0.0_dp ) , (-4.294180799072D+000 , 0.0_dp ) , 
     *  (-4.294180799072D+000, -1.0_dp) , ( -3.944481647220D+000,-1.0_dp ) , 
     *  (-3.496991526333D-001,-1.0_dp ) , (0.0_dp,-1.0_dp)/) 
C z computational
```

In the free form (usually `.f90`) use `&` at the of the line to continue on the next one.

```
complex(kind=dp),dimension(8),public:: zc = (/(0.0_dp,0.0_dp) ,(-3.496991526333D001,0.0_dp) , &
( -3.944481647220D+000 , 0.0_dp ) , (-4.294180799072D+000 , 0.0_dp ) , &
(-4.294180799072D+000, -1.0_dp) , ( -3.944481647220D+000,-1.0_dp ) , &
(-3.496991526333D-001,-1.0_dp ) , (0.0_dp,-1.0_dp)/) !z computational
```

You should read more about the correct soource form in any Fortran tutorial.